Astrometric alignment of JWST image
I have HST image and JWST image of galaxy mosaic.
HST wcs is correct as it was already updated with GAIA before.
But JWST wcs is shifted a bit as its wcs is not corrected.
So what I want is to correct the JWST mosaic image with that HST image.
I try to do with xyxy match in iraf but not working and also swarp astronetric alignment.
Please help how to correct this.
They are galaxy mosaic.

Have you tried plate solving the images with astrometry.net or ASTAP?  They should give you correct WCS coordinates after solving.
